# Url amigables sin perder los estilos css/js/imágenes

Tags: php, .htaccess

> Tengo un sitio web demasiado extenso editar las **URL** de los estilos `css` y archivos `js`, `imágenes` me costaría demasiado tiempo.

Estoy realizando pruebas trabajando en localhost

```
localhost/project/index.php
```

Las **URLs** amigable que deseo:

```
localhost/project/index/
```

Si el usuario modifica la **URLs** de esta manera: `localhost/project/index`

redireccionar a: `localhost/project/index/`

> Redireccionar cualquier **URLs** modificada sin barra `localhost/project/online/video/hd/free` a la **URLs** con barra al final `localhost/project/online/video/hd/free/`

De **URLs** simple

```
localhost/project/online.php
```

Mostrar de esta manera:

```
localhost/project/online/video/hd/free/
```

Lo he intentado con estos **Ejemplos:** `.htaccess`

> **Nota:** en estos primeros ejemplos de `.htaccess` los estilos `css`, y archivos `js`, `imágenes` se muestran sin ningún problema.

```
#Eliminar la extensión php/html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php

RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Resultado:**

```
http://www.example.com/index
http://www.example.com/online-video-en-hd-gratis
```

> El problema está en utilizar una barra `/` al final o varias adicionales `/../` al utilizar las barras se pierden los estilos `css`, entre los otros archivos  `js`, `imágenes`.

**Ejemplo uno:** (añadiendo una barra al final `/`)

```
http://www.example.com/index/
```

**Ejemplo dos:** (añadiendo varias barras `/`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/aventuras/$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

**Resultado:**

```
http://www.example.com/online/video/hd/aventuras/
```

> **Importante:**

He observado este sitio web http://crazycafe.net/demos/seo/ y su código fuente, los estilos `css` se mantiene de esta manera: `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` sin añadir una **URL absoluta** a los estilos `css` y sus archivos `js` y `imagenes` cargan sin problema.

He encontrado [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932078/httaccess-mod-rewrite-css-js-images-acess-issue) en **Stack Overflow** en Inlges, de cómo conservar los estilos CSS.

Unos de sus ejemplos era:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)?$ images/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.+)?$ js/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^topnav/(.+)?$ topnav/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^common-style\.css$ common-style.css
RewriteRule ^jquery\.js$ jquery.js
RewriteRule ^script/js/(.+)?$ script/$1 [NC,L]
```

Pero realmente no entiendo muy bien los secretos de **.htaccess**

Mi directorio(*carpeta*) de archivos es:

```
assets/css/style.css
assets/js/app.js
assets/fonts/icons/image.png
assets/fonts/ttf/roboto.ttf
assets/img/system/image.png
assets/img/logo.png
```

**¿Ahora mi pregunta es?**

Existe la posibilidad de corregir estos errores directamente desde el archivo **.htaccess** sin tener que cambiar la ruta de los archivos `css`, `js`, `imágenes` a una ruta (*absoluta*).

> Espero esta pregunta no se considere como demasiada extensa, edite mi pregunta a las recomendaciones de [MCVE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42297/url-amigables-sin-perder-los-estilos-css-js-im%C3%A1genes/42300?noredirect=1#comment73365_42300)

Comment: El problema que generarías si creas reglas para corregir el `path` a los `.css, .js`, etc. es que el navegador para cada ruta pensara que son archivos distintos (solo el server sabra que son los mismos). Mi consejo: A todos los `.css, .js`, etc. agregalos con la ruta absoluta, ej: `<script src="/libs/js/jquery.min.js">`, de esa forma no deberías tener ningún problema.

Comment: En `PHP` podrías crear un constante y dependiendo de si estas `local` u `online`, configuras la raíz del sistema. Ejemplo: `if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {
    define('APP_RAIZ', '/nombre_proyecto/public/');
} else {
    define('APP_RAIZ', '/');
}`. Luego en el `src o href` a tus `assets`, deberías imprimirla, ejemplo: `<link href="<?php echo APP_RAIZ; ?>assets/css/style.css"...`

Comment: No te preocupes por ese aviso. Para un trato de tú a tú me gusta más el chat que se activa. Hoy estoy de viaje, al medio día podré responder a tu edición, pero por lo que he leído por encima la cosa cambia completamente porque usas una URL base. Hay dos formas de solucionarlo, te pondré un ejemplo de cada una.

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo Genial el ejemplo realice pruebas y puedo trabajar tanto el `localhost` como en el servidor Saludos :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución podría ser redirigir todo lo que exista en los subdirectorios de último nivel a dichos archivos directamente, en vez de tratar de obtenerlos de sus rutas reales (las que generan el uso de las barras en las URLs amigables) o enviarlos a un PHP (si usas una regla genérica de redirección).

Estas son las reglas `.htaccess` que debes usar para detectar cualquier ruta "assets" que siga con un directorio llamado "css", "js", "fonts" o "img":

```
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Definimos la ruta base, por facilidad, una única vez
SetEnvIf RUTA_BASE ^(.*)$ RUTA_BASE=/project/

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(.+)$
# Y éstos coinciden con un archivo existente..
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{ENV:RUTA_BASE}assets/%1 -f
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:RUTA_BASE}assets/%1 [L,R]

# Tu/s regla/s
RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

He hecho las siguientes pruebas para comprobar su correcto funcionamiento:

- La URL `http://localhost/project/online/video/hd/free/` accede al script php llamado `online.php`.
- La URL `http://localhost/project/online/video/hd/free/assets/css/style.css` provoca el envío de una cabecera `Location: http://localhost/project/assets/css/style.css` que redirige al navegador al recurso existente.

Se han complicado las reglas por estar contenidas en un directorio arbitrario. Se podrían haber tecleado manualmente en el lugar que fuera necesario, para para facilitar la migración o cambio del directorio en un futuro, puedes definir fácilmente la ruta base al comienzo del `.htaccess`, así te evitas tener que cambiarlo en varias lugares del archivo (y, posiblemente, olvidarte de algún cambio).

Si las reglas hubieran estado en el raíz todo hubiera sido más fácil (y en eso se basaban mis reglas anteriores) porque usábamos la variable `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` sin agregar nada adicional. Podríamos haber usado `%{ENV:BASE}`, pero en la redirección también tendríamos que haber agregado esa misma cadena, y ahí ya no tenemos ninguna variable de entorno de apache que nos pudiera ayudar (o al menos yo no la conozco).

Espero que ahora la solución te funcione correctamente.

---

Se me olvidaba la segunda opción, aunque puede generar falsos positivos porque no puedo (no sé) comprobar la existencia del archivo, pero para minimizarlos hago más estricta la regla:

```
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Seleccionamos el directorio base para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /project/

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/" y subdirectorios previstos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/%1/%2 [L,R]

# Tu/s regla/s
RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51364/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-url-amigables-sin-perder-los-estilos-css-js).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Amigo he realizado las pruebas ahora en el servidor pero ahí no funciona las **URLs** como funciona correctamente en `localhost` que debo modificar en el `.htaccess` para que funcione en el servidor amigo.

Comment: ¿Qué tiene de diferente uno de otro? ¿Te permite usar `.htaccess`? ¿Tiene `mod_rewrite` activado? ¿Cambia la ruta base?

Comment: @OscarGarcia si amigo si permite ya hecho pruebas con otro código de .htaccess pero que debo poner en la ruta base por ejemplo yo suponía que era el nombre del dominio ejemplo example.com pero no funciona o estoy mal.

Comment: Es la ruta donde está tu página alojada dentro del dominio. Por ejemplo, en `http://localhost/project/index.php` sería `/project/`, en `http://www.tupagina.com/app/chachiweb/index.php` sería `/app/chachiweb/`.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Amigo tengo una nueva pregunta basada a este tema puedes ayudarme en ella amigo creo que sería mucho más fácil y para mí que mejor porque realmente conoces el código estas familiarizado en el [esta es mi pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43005/c%C3%B3mo-redireccionar-la-barra-slash-al-final-htaccess) amigo espero puedas ayudarme amigo.

Comment: ¿Te has planteado la idea de usar un framework que resuelva tus problemas de enrutamiento? ¿te has dado cuenta que la mayoría de tus dudas las tienen resueltas? Ánimo! Yo uso Slim para proyectos pequeños :)