# Error de .htaccess al subir al servidor

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Anteriormente había posteado [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42297/url-amigables-sin-perder-los-estilos-css-js-im%C3%A1genes) de cómo crear **URLs** amigables sin perder los estilos `css` y archivos `js` e `imágenes`.

En `localhost` funciona perfectamente sin ningun problema. El problema surgió a la hora de subir al servidor **hostgator** (*dominio principal vinculado al servidor*) las **URLs** amigables no funciona `www.example.com/online/video/hd/free/` me manda directamente a la página de error 404

realice pruebas con otras url amigables de otro archivo `.htaccess` para ver si el servidor estaba o no aceptando las **URLs** amigables pero funcionó perfectamente sin ningun problema.

El problema está en este archivo `.htaccess` o más bien en la ruta `RewriteBase /project/`

En **localhost** el proyecto es: *project* -> `localhost/project/index.php`

> Mencionó precisamente que el error es en la **ruta** `RewriteBase /project/` porque en `localhost` si no existe el nombre del proyecto o si existe y estuviera mal escrito el nombre o otro nombre que no sea: **project** sale el mismo error en el servidor, el mismo error que estoy teniendo.

```
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Seleccionamos el directorio base para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /project/

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/" y subdirectorios previstos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/%1/%2 [L,R]

# Tu/s regla/s
RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis/?$ video.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

He intentado de esta manera: `RewriteBase /www.example.com/` y de esta manera `RewriteBase /public_html/` pero sin exito no funciona.

> **NOTA:** El dominio ejemplo: `www.example.com` esta directo en **public_html** sin ninguna otra carpeta es decir no exite una carpeta como sucede en los otros dominios adicionales que estan igual en **public_html** pero en una carpeta especifica ejemplo una carpeta: `OTRAPAGINA.COM`
>
> ---

**public_html** *(como se puede observar existe el index.php igualmente el online.php directo en la carpeta **public_html** porque está vinculado al dominio principal al dominio configurado con el servidor.)*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Servidor es **linux / apache** realice pruebas con este archivo `.htaccess` y funciono bien al visitar la siguiente **URLs** `www.example.com/online/video/hd/free/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

La **URLs** concreta es: `www.example.com/online.php`

Pero en el archivo `.htaccess` que estoy teniendo problemas al visitar la misma **URL** `www.example.com/online/video/hd/free/` me direcciona a la pagina de error 404.

---

Asimismo, luego tengo pensado usar una segunda estructura:

```
public_html -> EXAMPLE.COM(<- carpeta) -> online.php
```

si no fuera el dominio principal, si no un dominido adicional y estuviera así, ¿cómo debería modificar el `.htaccess`?

Comment: ¿Qué servidor corre en el hosting? ¿Seguro que es Apache? ¿Seguro que tiene habilitado `mod_rewrite`? Además, `RewriteBase` no debería ser tu dominio. ¿Cuál es el root del dominio? ¿Debería funcionar en el root? Y si es así, ¿probaste sin `RewriteBase`? ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo concreto de una URL y a qué debería reescribir? ¿Cuál es la estructura de directorios real (en qué carpeta está `online.php`)?

Comment: @Mariano Hola, edite mi pregunta a base a las preguntas que has comentado amigo saludos :)

Comment: @JMick ¿Intentaste eliminando la línea `RewriteBase /project/`, o mismo con `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: @Mariano eliminando `RewriteBase /project/` funciona pero se pierden los estilos `css` y si lo dejo así `RewriteBase /` funciona perfectamente sin ningún problema y lo que es mejor conserva los estilos `css` con sus respectivos archivos, Ahora solo me queda una duda? si no fuera el dominio principal, si no un dominido adicional y estuviera así: public_html -> EXAMPLE.COM(<- carpeta) -> online.php

Comment: @JMick lo publiqué como respuesta. Espero que esté claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La directiva [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) especifica el prefijo de la URL que se usa como base (por directorio en el `.htaccess`) en todos los [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Es necesaria cuando se utilizan **rutas relativas**.

Por ejemplo, sirve para que las directivas:

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^carpeta/usuarios$  /carpeta/usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^carpeta/publicaciones$  /carpeta/publicaciones.php
```

Sean equivalentes (pero ahorrando algunos caracteres) a:

```python
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /carpeta
RewriteRule ^usuarios$  /usuarios.php
RewriteRule ^publicaciones$  /publicaciones.php
```

---

#### 1. Cambiar el RewriteBase para que aplique a la raíz del sitio

En el caso que de tu sitio, estás trabajando en el [root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) del dominio, por lo que simplemente se debe cambiar la línea:

```python
# Seleccionamos el directorio base para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /project/
```

Por:

```python
# Seleccionamos el directorio base para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /
```

---

#### 2. Segundo dominio

En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, depende de si `public_html/EXAMPLE.COM` es un segundo dominio configurado de esa forma (parecería ser así), o de si simplemente se accede a una carpeta con ese nombre.

1. **Si es un segundo dominio**

   Al ser otro dominio, el [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) de `http://example.com` directamente funcionará en esa carpeta, por lo que no sería necesario cambiar nada, ya que `http://example.com/online.php` buscará dentro de esa carpeta, sin necesidad de reescribir la URL.

   Es decir, sería válido trabajar también con:

   ```python
   RewriteBase /
   ```
2. **Si no está configurado como dominio** (no creo que sea éste el caso)

   Si las peticiones van direccionadas a, por ejemplo: `http://tusitio.com/EXAMPLE.COM/online.php`; entonces sí podría utilizarse un [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) como el siguiente para ahorrarse tener que utilizar la ruta absoluta:

   ```python
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /EXAMPLE.COM
   ```

Comment: Gracias @Mariano muy claro, Una consulta? esto no se basa a mi pregunta pero en mi archivo `.htaccess` como redireccionó siempre con una barra al final a las **URLs Amigable**? Ejemplo: `example.com/online/video/hd/free` redireccionar a `example.com/online/video/hd/free/` **Nota:** las dos formas funcionan sin problemas como también de esta manera `example.com/online-video-hd-free` igualmente así: `example.com/online-video-hd-free/` Es algo similar a utilizar un dominio con `www` o sin `www` *(Esto se especifica a Google en webmasters para evitar penalización por contenido duplicado)*

Comment: para evitar aquello lo ideal es redireccionar siempre con una barra al final `/` en la **URLs** amigable.

Comment: @J.Mick Una vez que te aseguraste que no es un archivo existente, sólo hay que crear un `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/` (aunque eso ya es una pregunta nueva, y hay muchos otros usuarios que te podrían haber contestado más rápido si lo publicabas).

Comment: @J.Mick Si son preguntas buenas, no hay límite... Lo decía porque así hubieses tenido respuesta inmediata

Comment: Vale amigo gracias no funcionó ahora realizó una nueva pregunta?