# url amigable y etiqueta base

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

Mi htaccess tiene el REWRITE activado:

```
#Activar RewriteEngine para URL's amigables
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /Carpeta

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ index.php?page=signup [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?page=login [L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ php/logout.php [L]
RewriteRule ^submit/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=submit&type=$1 [L]
```

En mi HTML/PHP tengo la etiqueta `<base>` apuntando a la misma carpeta que el htaccess.

```
<base href="/Carpeta">
```

Lo tengo así porque estoy haciendo pruebas en un servidor, el cual es gratuito y no puedo hacer subdominios, y creé un carpeta para probar este nuevo site.

Todas las URL's amigables no me funcionan:

`http://misitio.es/Carpeta/` Directamente no carga ningún recurso: imágenes, css, js... En el inspector de elemento, si abro el enlace de cada recurso no hay problema en visualizarlo, pero la web no lo encuentra por algún motivo.

Todas las URL's de los recursos son relativas.

En local no hay problema ni con el htaccess ni con la etiqueta `<base>`, y es lo que me está desconcertando.

¿Alguna idea de por qué ocurre esto?

**Añado**
He actualizado la pregunta, ya que con la etiqueta y el htaccess junto parecen estar en conflicto o algo. Además, si elimino la etiqueta base, manteniendo el del htaccess, ocurre que todas las url's amigables funcionan, exceptuando las que tengan más de un nivel:

`http://misitio.es/Carpeta/URLAMIGABLE/URLAMIGABLE2` esto no funciona (sería la última fila del htaccess).

Comment: hola, creo que te falta `RewriteRule ^(css|images|js) - [L]`

Comment: @AlbertArias con eso no funciona =/

Comment: ¿No puedes usar rutas absolutas (o relativas a la raíz)? Parece que el problema es que los recursos se cargan con rutas relativas que fallan (al haber 2 directorios en lugar de 1 y "romperse" la ruta relativa)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si bueno, supongo que para la versión de pruebas en este dominio podría hacerlo todo absoluto desde la raíz, pero lo suyo sería que pusiera donde lo pusiera (raíz, en una carpeta...) fuera capaz de detectar las rutas de los recursos

Comment: @Cheshire Prueba de esta manera `RewriteBase /` parece ser un problema similar que tuve hace varios días atrás puedes revisar está [Pregunta/Respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42916/error-de-htaccess-al-subir-al-servidor) es un problema similar al tuyo.

Comment: @J.Mick gracias por dar esa sugerencia, he probado con ese Rewrite, con <base> y sin y no hay manera.