# ¿Cómo redireccionar la barra / slash al final (/) .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, mod-rewrite

Siguiendo las recomendaciones de Google sobre la `redirección 301` la cual indica en sus artículos que puede ocurrir que las páginas estén disponibles tanto con una barra/slash al final `(/)` como sin ella. Por ejemplo:

- `http://www.example.com/pagina`
- `http://www.example.com/pagina/`

Si es así, en este caso se trata de una duplicidad que sólo puede resolverse redirigiendo una versión a la otra.

¿Ahora mi pregunta?

- ¿Cómo redireccionar todas las páginas sin barra/slash a la versión con barra/slash al final?

Lo intente adaptando este código a mi archivo `.htaccess` pero surgió problemas en la adaptación.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```

> **Importante:** En mi archivo `.htaccess` las **Urls** funciona de las dos formas sin problemas tanto con una barra/slash al final `(/)` como sin ella.

Mi archivo **.htaccess**

```
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Seleccionamos el directorio base     para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /project/

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar que sea un archivo (agrego comprobación
# para detectar también directorio) en cada conjunto de reglas
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/" y subdirectorios previstos
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/%1/%2 [L,R]

# Tu/s regla/s
RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis/?$ video.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

> Por otra parte no se si sea correcto permitir o no ingresar a la **URL** concreta **ejemplo:** `example.com/online.php` o redireccionar a la **URL** personalizada `example.com/online/video/hd/free/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión regular `^(.*[^/]$)` coincide con cualquier URL en la que el último caracter no sea una `/`. Al mismo tiempo, captura todo el texto en `$1`.

A eso, le agregamos una condición antes, para comprobar que no exista una archivo con ese nombre. Así, nos garantizamos que solamente se agregue la barra al final si no se está intentando acceder a un archivo (archivo, no carpetas):

```python
# si no existe un archivo que coincida con la solicitud...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# y si no termina con una barra, redireccionar a la misma dirección pero con la barra
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]
```

---

En tu caso en particular, creo que nos conviene hacerlo al revés: si existe el archivo, que no se comprueben más reglas; y si no existe, seguir con el resto. El `.htaccess` quedaría así:

```python
# Activamos mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# Seleccionamos el directorio base     para el RewriteRule
RewriteBase /project

# Aquí nos evitamos comprobar más reglas si el archivo existe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [QSA,L]

# Obtenemos todo lo que vaya tras "assets/" y subdirectorios previstos
# Entonces (si se cumplen todas las condiciones) redirigimos (R)
# y dejamos de evaluar el resto de reglas (L)
# Esta regla sólo coincide cuando /assets/../.. no está en el root
RewriteRule ./assets/(css|fonts|js|img)/(.+)$ assets/$1/$2 [L,NC,R]


#Si no tiene "/" al final, redireccionar a url con "/"
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]$) $1/ [R,QSA,L]

# Tu/s regla/s
RewriteRule ^online-video-en-hd-gratis/?$ video.php [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^online/video/hd/free/?$ online.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

**Pruebas:**

Lo subí a un hosting gratuito, en donde se pueden probar las direcciones:

1. http://mariano.freevar.com/43005/prueba/
   que accede directamente al recurso
   [image: Accede a /prueba/ con 200 OK]
2. http://mariano.freevar.com/43005/prueba
   que obtiene un 301 y redirecciona a la URL con `/` al final a la que accede
   [image: Obtiene un 301 Moved Permanently en /prueba y accede a /prueba/ con 200 OK]

Comment: No funciona me muestra error en localhost o **¡Objeto no localizado!**

Comment: @J.Mick Había eliminado mi respuesta porque no tenía como probarlo, pero ahora lo pude probar y funciona perfectamente. Dejé un ejemplo online en donde se puede verificar... Quizás el error que estás obteniendo viene por otro lado.

Comment: Hola @Mariano No funciona tal como está en el ejemplo pero después  de tanto ver que cambios hacer funcionó sin problemas al quitar esta función `RewriteRule ^ - [QSA,E]`

Comment: Tengo otra [pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48529/c%C3%B3mo-especificar-cach%C3%A9-de-navegador-pagespeed-insights) amigo sobre el mismo tema de las `.htaccess` No se si me podrías dar una manito saludos :)

Comment: No entendí? *esa regla lo que hace es evitar que se reescriba si se intenta acceder a un archivo que ya existe...*  un ejemplo.

Comment: @J.Mick Ejemplo: que cuando se acceda a un archivo existente, por ejemplo `tuweb.com/project/assets/img/ejemplo.png`, frene en esa regla, no se ejecuten el resto de las reglas del .htaccess, y por ende no intente agregarle una `/` al final

Answer (score 0):

intenta con esta regla:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras de que se trata la condición, y que está verificando que no tenga un punto. El `+` en `/+` es innecesario, y esta regla fallaría con carpetas en la raíz del sitio si tienen una sola letra.