# mi web no muestra los estilos usando urls amigables con htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, design

Estoy haciendo mi pagina  y uso  htaccess para crear urls amigables , en ello, le digo a un elemento  que me haga un href a un archivo "contacto"

```
html:
 <a href="contacto/">

.htaccess
Rewriterule  contacto/                                 contacto.html
```

y funciona bien el direccionamiento pero los estilos css no se muestran adecuadamente.

pero si ingreso a la pagina con el nombre del archivo.php o html si me los toma. 
¿Alguien sabe y puede explicarme por qué pasa esto y como solucionarlo usando htacces?

Comment: Seguramente cargas los estilos con urls relativas que no son válidas para la url amigable final, por ejemplo porque esté dentro de un directorio. Prueba con a cargar CSS con urls completas o revisa la relativa con referencia a la url amigable

Comment: Muy probablemente aquí puedas encontrar la solución https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42297/url-amigables-sin-perder-los-estilos-css-js-im%C3%A1genes?rq=1

Comment: gracias @LuisFernández la respuesta se ajusta a lo que requeria pero probe con quitarle la extension a los archivos en ves de usar el htacces para hacer el redireccionamiento y funciono asi .